# Nano v3 dual power source use & detection

Tags: arduino-nano

I would like to run a Nano 3.0 from both the VIN (mains power supply 7V) and USB power (backup). I understand it selects the highest voltage and switches to VIN at 6.6V. However I am unsure of the following:

1. How is it possible to detect which power source is being used?
2. How is it possible to detect if the source has been switched?
3. How is it possible to detect if the power source NOT in use has been disconnected.

Comment: Could you not take a line of each of the inputs and (after suitable level shifting) test them using two of the digital pins?

Answer (score 2):

To check, if VIN is connected, you can connect VIN through a voltage divider to a digital pin (as suggested in the comment of Code Gorilla). For checking the USB connection you would have to connect VUSB to another digital pin. Since VUSB is not exposed on a pin, this could be difficult to do, but it is possible.

But note, that this would also show a disconnect, when the voltage drops (e.g. empty battery). When you want to detect real mechanical disconnects, you need a power jack with an extra switch integrated.

Let's take a look at the schematics: [Arduino Nano 3.0 Schematics](https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoNano30Schematic.pdf)
[image: Schematics of Arduino Nano v3.0 voltage supply]
The selection of voltage supply is done by the diode D1. If the voltage resultung from the VIN regulator is higher than VUSB - diode_voltage_drop, the diode is closing and the power comes from VIN. If the voltage resulting from VIN is lesser, the current can flow from VUSB. How much power is really drawn from USB depends on the voltage difference.

So - to detect which source is actually used - you can measure the voltage on the diode with an analog measurement with the ADC or through connecting for example a comparator and using a digital pin.

Note that the voltage on the diode can be positive or negative, depending on which source is used.